# How to disable all input boxes through loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting all input box ids from the form and i need to disable all input boxes,

I have tried with below code

```
var results = [];
$('#form input').each(function(){
    results.push({
        id: this.id,
        value: this.value
    });
});
var i;
for( i= 0; i< results.length ; ++i)
{
    var input_id = results[i].id; //getting all input box ids
    $('#input_id ').prop('disabled', true);
}
```

Can any one help on this please??

Comment: Can you share the html you use?

Comment: @Baboo_ I got the answer thank you.

Comment: @Andreas - OMG, how did I miss that the loop was *over the inputs*?! Fixed [the answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52028102/157247).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$('#input_id ')` looks for an element with `id="input_id"`, **literally**. To use the `input_id` variable, use string concatenation:

```
    $('#' + input_id).prop('disabled', true);
//      ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

...or in ES2015+, a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
    $(`#${input_id}`).prop('disabled', true);
//    ^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

---

Side note: Instead of `$('#form input').each` and `results.push`, you could use jQuery's [`map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/). But there's no reason to do two loops. Instead, just call `prop` on the result of `$("#form input").each(...)`. jQuery is *set-based*, and when you use a mutator operation (like `.prop("disabled, true)`), it applies to all elements in the set:

```
var results = [];
$('#form input').each(function(){
    results.push({
        id: this.id,
        value: this.value
    });
}).prop("disabled", true); // ***
```

Alternately, you can use `map` (and [`get`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) at the end to get a true array instead of a jQuery object) and just set `disabled` directly in the callback:

```
var results = $('#form input').map(function() {
    this.disabled = true; // ***
    return {
        id: this.id,
        value: this.value
    };
}).get();
```

Comment: @manjunath - No worries! I've added an alternative to the answer. Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks a lot T.J Crowder.

Answer (score 1):

Why not a single line as it seems all inputs are concerned ?

```
$("#form input").prop('disabled', true);
```

or

```
$("#form input[id]").prop('disabled', true);
```

if you want to select only those with id